# How to properly implement CodeLens in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a extension for Visual Studio Code and need to display a CodeLens in the editor.

What is the best way to implement it?

Should I create a CodeLens with a command in `provideCodeLenses` or update it in `resolveCodeLens`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how complex your code lenses are to compute.

- If the code lenses are very simple and can always be created in a fixed amount of time, you only need to implement `provideCodeLens`.
- If creating the code lenses may involve intensive computation or any sort of non-deterministic behavior – such as network – then `provideCodeLens` should only return skeleton Code Lenses with ranges. You would then complete the CodeLens' `command` in `resolveCodeLens`, which will only be called when the CodeLens actually needs to be displayed.

Overall, splitting your CodeLens implementation between `provideCodeLenses` and `resolveCodeLens` is the safest choice.

Comment: I have to create the same thing for a language that is not part of .net but we do have Visual Studio as the editor. Can you show me where to find proper documentation on how to start with this. I am starting from scratch here I'm afraid